# How to configure ActiveMQ memory settings under Apache Tomee?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I have an embedded ActiveMQ under Apache TomEE. TomEE configures JMS in a file called tomee.xml, in my case, it's configured like this

```
<Resource id="Default JMS Resource Adapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig = broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)?persistent=true
    ServerUrl = tcp://localhost:61616
    DataSource = MyDataSource
</Resource>
```

Now, I'd like to specify custom memory settings, which is done in the activemq.xml file. TomEE can load activemq.xml configuration using Spring XBeans if I add , like this (I think)

```
<Resource id="Default JMS Resource Adapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig = xbean:file:conf/activemq.xml
    ServerUrl = tcp://localhost:61616
    DataSource = MyDataSource
</Resource>
```

See http://tomee.apache.org/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html

Is that right?

I've added the 5 jars into tomee's lib path, just as indicated in the link above.

And then, I have an activemq.xml like this

```
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional information regarding 
    copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may 
    obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed 
    on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the 
    License. -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1" />
                    <pendingQueuePolicy>
                        <vmQueueCursor />
                    </pendingQueuePolicy>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="128 mb" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb" />
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb" />
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="anythingHere" uri="broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)?persistent=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

but obviously, I am doing something wrong here, because JMS does not start and returns an error message like

```
SEVERE: Failed to connect to broker [tcp://localhost:61616]: Could not connect to
broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

what am I missing here?

UPDATE - more info then

then I've added the absolute path to the activemq.xml file because I could not make it work from inside eclipse (I know, this is probably more like eclipse's fault)

then I've changed some invalid XML such as

```
<!--             <destinationPolicy> -->
<!--                 <policyMap> -->
<!--                     <policyEntries> -->
<!--                         <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1" /> -->
<!--                         <pendingQueuePolicy> -->
<!--                             <vmQueueCursor /> -->
<!--                         </pendingQueuePolicy> -->
<!--                     </policyEntries> -->
<!--                 </policyMap> -->
<!--             </destinationPolicy> -->
```

and replaced with site's default

```
<destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
                <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                     slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                     by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                     For more information, see:

                     http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                -->
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
              <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                   For more information, see:

                   http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

              <pendingQueuePolicy>
                <vmQueueCursor/>
              </pendingQueuePolicy>
              -->
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

after adding kahadb from the maven repository and switching from activemq-all to activemq-spring and defining the bean into activemq.xml as

```
    </broker>

    <bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
      </bean>

</beans>
```

finally.... I am getting a new error

```
SEVERE: Failed to load: URL [file:/home/leoks/EclipseIndigo/workspace2/Servers     /TomEE1.6.0-STABLE-config/activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name  'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in URL [file:/home/leoks /EclipseIndigo/workspace2/Servers/TomEE1.6.0-STABLE-config/activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [broker]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in URL [file:/home/leoks/EclipseIndigo/workspace2/Servers/TomEE1.6.0-STABLE-config/activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [broker]
```

after some google, some solutions seems to be related somehow to the incapacity of activemq to load the XML (makes sense, since XML is a recent technology, invented in 96, almost 20 years ago)

I am pulling my hair off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you transport connector configuration should look like this:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="tcp" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

See the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html) for connectors.

Comment: almost there... now I get Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:(...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory

Comment: Are you using maven? If yes, add the `activemq-spring` artifact to your dependency list. If not then manually add the `activemq-spring-<version>.jar` from the activemq installation to your classpath.

Comment: yeah, I've figured this out... I am almost there. I had to remove some invalid XML and now I am just trying to set the jdbcPersistenceAdapter. Also had to use the absolute path in tomee.xml... seems like a struggle to configure something that should be simple

Comment: BTW, trying to run from inside eclipse. not maven

Comment: after all, the last thing I've fixed was the connector, that was using tomee syntax, not activemq syntax as you correctly pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, and i'm also pulling my hair out because is not working at all